# Add dynamically a tab in bootstrap with jsf content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, richfaces

second part of my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799267/show-dynamically-created-tab-content-in-bootstrap), I want that the added tab content some `back bean value` something like `#{backBean.htmlpage} in a`h:outputText but it doesn't seem to work with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a JSF component on the page with JavaScript. It has to go through the server first.

Comment: Hidden input did the job.